# What's the deal with overloading virtual functions in C++?

Tags: c++

The GCC manual contains the following explanation of the warning option -Woverloaded-virtual:

Warn when a function declaration hides virtual functions from a base class.  For example, in:

```
struct A {
    virtual void f();
};

struct B: public A {
    void f(int);
};
```

The `A` class version of `f` is hidden in `B`, and code like:

```
B* b;
b->f();
```

Fails to compile.

What is the problem with this code? If it fails to compile, why is it a warning and not an error message? What is the canonical way to fix this and why?

Comment: Name lookup strikes again - `void B::f(int);` is not a virtual function (different signature) and hides the name of  `void A::f();`  Someone with a degree in C++ name lookup will be needed for the full explanation.

Comment: `B* b;` has not been initialized, so `b->f();` will be undefined behavior.  The `b->f();` tries to call `B::f(int)` but cannot, because it is missing a parameter, so fails to compile.  Hiding a base class function due to parameter overloading is probably a boo-boo, which is why the compiler is providing a warning.  (The compiler is opting to do that, it isn't required by the standard, iirc.)

Comment: The warning is on `void f(int);` declaration in `B` (because it's likely to lead to errors later). `b->f()` should in fact produce an error. Does it not?

Comment: While `b` is not actually pointing to an object of type `B` (it is garbage), and while there are no definitions for A::f() or B::f(int), neither of these are the issue the OP is referring to (and, in fact, the first of these two issues will not prevent compilation). It has to do with name hiding. See cdhowie's answer

Comment: To be clear: `B::f` does **not** overload `A::f`. The two names are defined in different scopes, so they do not overload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introducing a name that is inherited from an ancestor type causes that name to be hidden in the derived type.  This is why `b->f();` does not compile.

The warning comes from the *declaration* of `B::f`.  The compiler is telling you that this new declaration *does not* overload or override the function inherited from `A`.  It hides it within `B`'s scope.  Sometimes you might want this, and there is nothing technically wrong with it, which is why it is not an error.  However, because `A::f` is hidden in `B`, you can't invoke it (statically) on a `B` value/reference.

**Note that this has nothing to do with the inherited member function being virtual** (though you would not receive the warning about the declaration of `B::f` if `A::f` were not virtual, nevertheless both will fail to compile `b->f()` for the same reason).  Perhaps more interesting, note that [a type deriving `B` can override `A::f` even though it is not visible in `B`](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2b1de076863d73d).

To have both (an overloaded `f()` in `B`) you can explicitly bring the name `f` from `A` into `B`:

```
struct B: public A {
    using A::f;
    void f(int);
};
```

Now both `f()` overloads are visible within `B`.  Note that `void f()` is still virtual, but `void f(int)` was not declared virtual and so it isn't.

Another (ugly) workaround is to upcast the `B` pointer/reference to an `A` pointer/reference:

```
B *b = new B;
static_cast<A*>(b)->f();
```

Or, with a value instead of a pointer:

```
B b;
static_cast<A&>(b).f();
```

This uses the virtual function through the `A` type, where it is not hidden.

Comment: Beat me to it. For more information regarding name hiding and why it exists (though its purpose is somewhat debatable), see here: http://www.programmerinterview.com/c-cplusplus/c-name-hiding/

Comment: Thanks. I guess they should explicitly mention that `b->f(3)` compiles (as I presume) for the sake of illustration.

Comment: @shuhalo I didn't mention that because it's not surprising. However, I did just edit my answer to make it clear that it has nothing to do with the inherited member function being virtual. You would see the same behavior with non-virtual functions, except for the lack of a warning about the declaration of `B::f`.

Comment: Just to be clear, as was speaking of "them", the GCC developers and documenters. Your answer has been very helpful.

Comment: @shuhalo Ah, I misread. Thanks for clarifying that! :)